# Stable Baselines 3 - BaseFeaturesExtractor weights are not updated

Tags: python, pytorch, stable-baselines

I am working with Stable-Baselines 3 and want to create a **custom feature extractor**. Unfortunately, the weights of the layers (here: "self.cnn" and "self.linear") are **not updated** by backpropagation.

Here is my CustomCNN(BaseFeaturesExtractor) class:

```
class CustomCNN(BaseFeaturesExtractor):
    """
    :param observation_space: (gym.Space)
    :param features_dim: (int) Number of features extracted.
        This corresponds to the number of unit for the last layer.
    """
    def __init__(self, observation_space: gym.spaces.Box, features_dim: int = 256):
        super(CustomCNN, self).__init__(observation_space, features_dim)
        # We assume CxHxW images (channels first)
        # Re-ordering will be done by pre-preprocessing or wrapper
        self.cnn = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(3, 16, kernel_size=8, stride=4, padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=0),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Flatten(),
        )
        self.linear = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(256, features_dim), 
            nn.ReLU()
        )


    def forward(self, observations: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        if np.random.uniform() < 0.01: # ~ Every 100-th iteration
            print(list(self.cnn.parameters())[0])
        cnn_output = self.cnn(observations)
        linear_output = self.linear(cnn_output)
        return linear_output
```

This is the code where I mount the class into my framework:

```
policy_kwargs = dict(
        features_extractor_class=CustomCNN,
        features_extractor_kwargs=dict(features_dim=128),
        activation_fn=torch.nn.ReLU,
        net_arch=[128, 128, dict(pi=[64, 64], vf=[64, 64])
   ])
model = PPO("CnnPolicy", env, policy_kwargs=policy_kwargs, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=50000000, callback=callback, reset_num_timesteps=False)
```

I thereby check every ~100th timestep the weights of the first layer, but the weights do not change. Is there something that I am lacking?

**Update:**

The bug is solved/turned out not to be a bug: https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3/issues/997.